# Clickable menu Crashing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a test Code for a school project that was assigned to the class but when i run the code the tkinter buttons load up, however when you press the button on the Maths section(the only one done), the code would crash, any help would be nice.

```
from tkinter import *

Window_Blank = Tk()
#Advanced Define
def MathA():
answer = input()
answer = int(answer)
print("If A=12*2 and B=15*3, What does AB-B= ")
if answer == 1035:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
    print("The Answer was 1035")
def Math():
  print(MathA())
  return
def Science():
  return

def Agriculture():
 return
def Geographical():
 return

#Basic Define
Frame1 = Frame(Window_Blank)
Frame2 = Frame(Window_Blank)
Frame3 = Frame(Window_Blank)
Frame4 = Frame(Window_Blank)
Button1 = Button(Frame1, text="Math Questions", fg="red", command=Math)
Button2 = Button(Frame2, text="Science Questions", fg="blue", command=Science)
Button3 = Button(Frame3, text="Agricultural Questions", fg="green", command=Agriculture)
Button4 = Button(Frame4, text="Geographical Questions", fg="purple", command=Geographical)

#Framework for the menu
Frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
Frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
Frame3.grid(row=0, column=2)
Frame4.grid(row=0, column=3)
Button1.grid(row=1)
Button2.grid(row=2)
Button3.grid(row=3)
Button4.grid(row=4)

Window_Blank.mainloop()
```

Comment: How does it crash? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: it just stops responding

Comment: It stops because it's waiting for you to type something. Are you saying that when you type something at the prompt it still hangs? And why are you using command line input in a GUI program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
def MathA():
    print("If A=12*2 and B=15*3, What does AB-B= ")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == 1035:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print("The Answer was 1035")
```

And:

```
def Math():
  MathA()
  return
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!